# What is meant by $f : [a,b] \times D \rightarrow R^m$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, nonlinear-system

I am working through Nonlinear Systems by Khalil.
Lemma 3.1 states the following

Let $f : [a,b] \times D \rightarrow R^m$ be continuous for some domain $D \subset R^n$. Suppose that $[\partial f/\partial x]$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b]\times D$. If, for a convex subset $W \subset D$, there is a constant $L \geq 0$ such that
$$\left|\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x)\right|\right| \leq L$$
on $[a,b]\times W$, then
$$||f(t,x) - f(t,y)|| \leq L ||x-y||$$
for all $t \in [a,b],\space x \in W$, and $y \in W$.

I am a bit uncertain how to think about the $f : [a,b] \times D \rightarrow R^m$.
Is it the Cartesian product? Are we slicing out part of the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $[a,b]\times D$ is the Cartesian product of $[a,b]$ and $D$. And, no, the author is not slicing out part of the domain.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply. Would you mind going into a bit more details what he is doing then?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: What is the result of taking the cartesian product of a closed set with a domain?

Comment: Is t the closed set and D the x vector?

Comment: Since $D\subset\Bbb R^n$, $[a,b]\times D\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}$. For instance, if $D=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y>x\}$, if $a=-1$, and if $b=2$, then$$[a,b]\times D=\{(t,x,y)\in\Bbb R^3\mid t\in[-1,2]\text{ and }y>x\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! It makes a lot more sense now. :)